# Difference between return {} and return Object{}

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, list-initialization

Is there any significant difference between this two functions?

```
struct Object {
    Object(int i) : i{i}
    {
    }

    int i;
};

Object f() { return {1}; }
Object g() { return Object{1}; }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The 1st one is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization), the approriate constructor (i.e. `Object::Object(int)`) will be selected to construct the return value.

The 2nd one will construct a temporary `Object` by [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#direct-list-initialization), (which also calls `Object::Object(int)`), then copy it to the return value. Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (which is guaranteed from C++17), the copy- or move- construction is omitted here.

So for your example they have the same effect; `Object::Object(int)` is used to construct the return value. Note that for the 1st case, if the constructor is `explicit` then it won't be used.

> - direct-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered)
> - copy-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered, but only non-explicit constructors may be called)

Answer (score 8):

No difference in your example as written. But a difference will arise if you mark the constructor `explicit`. Then only `g` would be correct, because it does direct initialization, whereas `f` does a form of copy initialization and cannot use an explicit constructor.